# Retrieve primary key ID before persisting using sessionfactory in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have used below code to get primary key in hibernate before persisting Object. But its inserting duplicate rows in DB.

The issue here I am facing is:
1. I am getting two values for primary key. One when I invoke the flushPerson() method to get 'id' before persisting Person Object.
2. Other when I invoke save method, to save Person object. In this method also 'Id' is getting incremented.

**PersonController.java**

```
public Person createNewPerson(String .....){
    Person per = new Person();
    personManager.flushPerson(per);
    RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RandomNumberGenerator();
    String randomStrng = rng.generateRandomNumber();
    String cientCode = per.getId()+randomStrng;
    per.setPersonClientCode(cientCode);
    per.setPersonClient();
    per.setPersonField();
    personManager.save(per);
}
```

**PersonHibernateDao.java**

```
@Override
public void flushPerson(Person per) {       
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(per);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); 
}

@Override
public void save(Person per) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(per);
}
```

What am I missing here? I want to save object with only primary key 'id' that is created in flush method and it should insert only one row.

Comment: when you saving in your database 
**Person p  = personManager.save(per); 
sout( p.getId() );**
print out and check you are getting an id or not if you are get an id then return it :)

Comment: @Navin Gelot i am getting id,But issue is, i am getting two incremented ids. one in, when i invoke flushPerson() ex: assume here 'id' will be 5, here it stores one row with primary key as 5 in DB. Other one in save(Person) where it stores 6 as primary key in DB.

Comment: Then just use one of flush() and save(), not both.

Answer (score 0):

Change your save method to:

```
@Override
public Person save(Person per) {
 return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(per);
}
```

Then, in `PersonController` you can do:

```
Person per = new Person();
//whatever Mutators you need
per = personManager.save(per);
//Now you can get id and no duplicate rows will be inserted
```

Comment: if i use only flush(), will transaction be comitted in current session?